# ipyleaflet with GEE in JupyterLab doesn't show layer

Tags: google-earth-engine, conda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the interactive map example for GEE community - Python API on JupyterLab (https://github.com/gee-community/ee-jupyter-contrib/blob/master/examples/getting-started/display-interactive-map.ipynb) .

I get only the osm basemap **without** the Sentinel-2 layer & I don't get any errors. I have installed `folium`, `ipywidget`, `ipyleaflet`.

What can be the problem? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EE Python API has been updated, breaking backwards compatibility. This is the way you get the tile URL these days:

```
def GetTileLayerUrl(ee_image_object):
  map_id = ee.Image(ee_image_object).getMapId()
  tile_fetcher = map_id['tile_fetcher']
  return tile_fetcher.url_format
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel !